# How to check if node exists in Firebase Database with Flutter/Dart

Tags: firebase-realtime-database, dart, flutter

I've seen this question answered multiple times already for JavaScript and other languages. There, it always comes down to get a snapshot and use a method called `exists()` to check. But in Dart/Flutter, there is no such method. Here's what I have for now:

```
devicesRef.child(deviceId).once().then((DataSnapshot data) {
    print(data.key);
    print(data.value);        
});
```

I want to check whether a node called `deviceId` already exists.

So how can I check if a node exists in Firebase Realtime Database with Dart/Flutter?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I would guess, since there is no such thing as a null child value in Realtime Database, that you could simply check if `data.value` is null.

Answer (score 3):

Pass Your `DatabaseReference` to this method , and will return true if it Exists

```
 Future<bool> rootFirebaseIsExists(DatabaseReference databaseReference) async{
    DataSnapshot snapshot = await databaseReference.once();

    return snapshot !=null;
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Future<bool> isUserRegistered(String idToken) async{
 DataSnapshot dataSnapshot = await databaseReference.child('app').child('users').child(idToken).once();
 return dataSnapshot.value!=null;
}
```

Comment: Please don't post only code as answer, but also provide an explanation what your code does and how it solves the problem of the question. Answers with an explanation are usually more helpful and of better quality, and are more likely to attract upvotes.

Answer (score 0):

Updated answer:

```
static Future<bool> isNodeExists(DatabaseReference databaseReference) async {
var result = await databaseReference.once();
return result.snapshot.value != null;
}
```